# Passport.js, Sessions, & React | Accessing req.user from any route other than the /login route is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I have a React client setup at localhost:3000 and a node.js server at localhost:5000

I'm trying a simple auth flow in which the client tries to authenticate with the server using Passport.js Google OAuth2.0 and staying authenticated using express-sessions with a MongoDB store.

I believe the reason I'm finding req.user is undefined is because of my lack of understanding of how the auth flow is supposed to work versus any issues with the actual code.

I'm initiating the auth flow through the following code in the react client:

```
<Button href="http://localhost:5000/auth/google">
        Login using Google
</Button>
```

The following is my **auth.js** file:

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const router = express.Router();

// @desc    Auth with Google
// @route   GET /auth/google
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }));

// @desc    Google auth callback
// @route   GET /auth/google/callback
router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        failureRedirect: "/",
        successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/dashboard",
    })
);

// @desc    Logout user
// @route   /auth/logout
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

The following is my Google Strategy configuration:

```
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/User");

module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(
        new GoogleStrategy(
            {
                clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback",
            },
            async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                const newUser = {
                    googleId: profile.id,
                    displayName: profile.displayName,
                    firstName: profile.name.givenName,
                    lastName: profile.name.familyName,
                    image: profile.photos[0].value,
                };

                try {
                    let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

                    if (user) {
                        done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        user = await User.create(newUser);
                        done(null, user);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            }
        )
    );

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) => done(err, user));
    });
};
```

The following code is my **index.js** which brings everything together:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

// Dotenv config
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config({
    path: "./config/config.env",
});

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// MongoDB config
connectDB();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

// Middleware

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Sessions
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "stackoverflow",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/posts", require("./routes/posts"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening @ port ${PORT}`));
```

I am fetching posts from the DB through one of the routes after user login:

```
...
// @desc Get all posts
// @route GET /posts

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const posts = Post.find(function (error, posts) {
        if (error) return console.error(error);
        console.log(req.user) // <------ is undefined
        res.json(posts);
    });
});
```

I'm assuming that after the user is being redirected to the dashboard and then sending a request to the route to get all posts, the user is not authenticated? Although I redirected the user towards this route after authenticating him?

The goal is definitely not to fetch the user at the /posts route but create a separate /user route that returns the user to the client, but that also results in req.user being undefined.

Comment: I think you are just missing the passport authentication middleware for the `/` `GET` route. If you want to apply a middleware to all routes by default you can use `app.use( ...)`.

Comment: @PascalLamers I'm not sure which middleware that is? If it's worth mentioning, accessing the `/ GET` route directly through the browser (by going to localhost:5000/posts), it logs the user successfully but not if accessed through the client. My bet is that the client is not authenticated but I'm not sure what to do about that?

Comment: It could be something with that yes, so authentication happens through :5000 . Here is an example for Facebook Authentication Flow (which is similiar). https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example . They are not using a full URL for callback. You can try that or using :3000 in the callback ?

Comment: I did try having just the route in the callback instead of the full URL. That didn't work, unfortunately. I'm not sure about having :3000 in the callback since the callback has to go through the server @ port 5000. Thank you for the example. The only difference is that they're rendering the page through the server instead of having a client-server setup the way I have it going.

Comment: Ah I think I can remember I had a similar problem when using passport in a client rendered site. One good Idea is to use environment variables for the ports (development vs. production) this way you don't need to change it all the time. Another thing I did was in the callback controller , redirecting to the frontend with the accessToken as query paremeter, this way I could access it and the client side app. But I was using a non-cookie based approach on doing things. Are you using Google just for authenticating the user or are you planning to use the Google API as well on behalf of the user ?

Comment: Yep, env variables are the way to go. I'm just using it to authenticate then grab the name and the profile picture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally got it to work.

I had to edit two things,

First (Server Side):

I had to setup CORS to allow cookies to pass through as such:

```
app.use(
    cors({
         origin: "http://localhost:3000", // allow to server to accept request from different origin
         methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
         credentials: true, // allow session cookie from browser to pass through
   })
);
```

Second (Client Side):

I had to let Axios know that it has to send the cookie alongside the request as such:

```
axios
     .get("http://localhost:5000/auth/user", { withCredentials: true })
     .then(console.log)
     .catch(console.error);
```

where the `/auth/user` route is defined as such:

```
router.get("/user", (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
        res.json(req.user);
    }
});
```

These mistakes could have been avoided had I had a better understanding of the entire authentication process, of which now I do.

We live and we learn.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, you saved me a great deal of time.

Answer (score 0):

At first haidousm's answer did not work for me, what I did was I added `{ withCredentials: true }` to the post request for my login as well.