# why is user.id accessible on a get request but not a post request? passport.js and mern stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Happy Sunday

I am trying to access the req.user property in a post request to the backend by it is coming back as undefined.

It shows up perfect when I run the

```
app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user);
    })
```

But when I run the route below req.user is coming back as undefined.......

```
 app.post('/templates/create', async (req, res) => {
        const { template, body } = req.body  
        const newTemplate = new Template({
            template: template,
            body: body,
            _user: req.user.id  
        })
        try {
            await newTemplate.save()
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Successfully saved template"
                })
        } catch (err) {
            return console.log(err)
            }
        });
```

I cant seem to understand what is going On?

Here is the Routes file below

```
const passport = require('passport');
const requireLogin = require('../middlewares/requireLogin')
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');
const Template = require('../models/Template');
const corsOptions ={
    origin: true, 
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}

module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email']
    }));

    app.get(
        '/auth/google/callback',
       passport.authenticate('google'),
       (req, res) => {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    );

    app.post('/templates/create', async (req, res) => {
        const { template, body } = req.body  
        const newTemplate = new Template({
            template: template,
            body: body,
            _user: req.user.id  
        })
        try {
            await newTemplate.save()
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Successfully saved template"
                })
        } catch (err) {
            return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    
    


    app.get('/api/logout', cors(), (req, res) => {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
    });
    app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user);
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example to debug?

Comment: Is the user object placed inside req.body for a post request?

Answer (score 0):

because when use passport.authenticate it will serialize  user to req object
but you didn't add passport.authenticate middleware to the   **app.post('/templates/create', async (req, res) => {** so user it won't serialize  to req and it will be undefined.

Comment: how do I add that middleware to the post request? I did

Comment: I did this and it still is undefined ```router.route('/templates/create', passport.authenticate()).post(userCtrl.createTemplate).get(userCtrl.listTemplate)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152640/passport-js-sessions-react-accessing-req-user-from-any-route-other-than-th    maybe this could help you

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a user id while doing the post, but the user id cannot be reached. You can create an authentication bearer after login using jwt or cookie. In this way, user id can be reached.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue after two days of trying. the issue was with my frontend not sending the credentials.

Here is how I was sending the post request originally, and req.user would return undefined

When doing axios.post like this below, axios doesnt automatically include the credentials, even when I added {credentials: 'include'} directly after the comma like this
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/template/create', {credentials: 'include', createTemplate})

it was still broken

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:5000/template/create', createTemplate)
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.error) {
        setCreateTemplate({...createTemplate, error: response.error})
        console.log('this ran')
      } else {
          setCreateTemplate({...createTemplate, error: '', redirectToRefferrer: true})
        
        toast.success(`Successfully save your template as ${createTemplate.template}`);
   
      }
    })
   };
```

The solutions was to change the post request like so

```
axios({
      url:"http://localhost:5000/templates/create",
      method:"POST",
      data: createTemplate, 
      withCredentials: true
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.error) {
        setCreateTemplate({...createTemplate, error: response.error})
        console.log('this ran')
      } else {
          setCreateTemplate({...createTemplate, error: '', redirectToRefferrer: true})
        
        toast.success(`Successfully save your template as ${createTemplate.template}`);
   
      }
    })
   };
```

I find it so strange the axios.post with credentials include didnt work in the beginning. can anyone elaborate why that is so?